# Grouping markers in google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

How would one go about implementing the same type of marker grouping as found on this website? http://clevertrail.com/

Is this something that is delivered by the google maps api? If not, how can one create these kinds of groupings?

Any suggested solutions is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use marker cluster for that: http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries. It does the grouping in JS but it's not very efficient.

Answer (score 3):

you can try this code with your respective locations and values..
you need to include the marker cluster js to your code..get it from here [markerclustrer.js](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/markerclustererplus/src/markerclusterer.js?r=360)

```
<script>
var markerCluster = [];
var all_markers = [];
var infowindows = [];
var map;
function initialize(){
var mapProp = {
  center:center,
  zoom:5,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap")
  ,mapProp);
addmarker(lat,long); //creating the marker....; function call can be looped
markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, all_markers); //setting the markers' array as a cluster on google maps
}
function addmarker(lat,lng)
{
      var mycenter = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:mycenter,
        });
      all_markers.push(marker); //making an array of markers
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

After some investigating they seem to be using a third party plugin/extension to handle the marker grouping.. found on this page: http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries